# How can I configure GGTS to format Groovy code based on project formatters?

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, groovy, code-formatting

I'm attempting to configure version 3.4.0 of the Eclipse-based [Groovy/Grails Tool Suite (GGTS)](http://spring.io/tools/ggts) to format both Java and Groovy code.  From what I've read, it seems that Groovy inherits almost all of the rules from the configured Java formatter.

I've configured a project-specific formatter for Java code via Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Configure Project Specific Settings.  When I open any `.java` files in my Grails project and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, the code is formatted beautifully.

When I open any `.groovy` files in my Grails project (from either `src/groovy` or `grails-app`) and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, very little happens.  GGTS seems to remove unnecessary semicolons and trailing whitespace, but does not appear to make any substantial formatting changes (e.g. whitespace around parentheses and braces, newline rules around braces, etc.).

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding the Groovy formatting in GGTS?  Does it need to be invoked via some other method other than the aforementioned keyboard shortcut?  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

For what it's worth, my GGTS environment is a clean installation--no additional plugins, custom editors, etc.

Comment: The groovy formatter has significantly fewer options than the Java Formatter.  Take a look at Preferences -> Groovy -> Formatting.  All it can do is add/remove newlines after curly braces, wrap long lines, and ensure that indentation is correct. Also, I believe that formatting is always workspace wide. There is no project-specific formatting available.  Can you include a code snippet that you expect to be formatted, but isn't?

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg In my case, I expected the formatter to add spaces around operators and `=` in assignments and annotations.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code before, the code after, and what you would have expected/wanted?